# How do I sort a List of Dictionaries based off of a value in a key within the Dictionary in C# .NET Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

So I have a `List` of `Dictionary<string, string> dict` and I want to sort the `List` alphabetically off the `dict["Title"]` value.

How do I go about doing that?

And, what if I want to take the value of `dict["Title"]`, modify it as `string title = dict["Title"] + "xyz";`, and then use the modified `title` as the sorting value of that `dict` (without actually changing `dict["Title"]`)...

How would I go about doing that as well?

Thanks.

Comment: As I know, you can have only 1 "title" key for each dictionary; so what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Sort on that one "title" key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq it:

```
var dicts = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

var sort = dicts.OrderBy(x => x.ContainsKey("Title") ? x["Title"] : string.Empty);
var sort2 = dicts.OrderBy(x => x.ContainsKey("Title") ? x["Title"] + "xyz" : string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are trying to say something like this:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list;
```

And what you want to do is something like

```
list.Sort();
```

But not quite.
So, what you can do instead is either make a wrapper class for `Dictionary<string, string>` and then overload the compare methods, or you could make a comparison method like

```
static int CompareDicts(Dictionary<string, string> x, Dictionary<string, string> y) {
  return String.Compare(x["Title"],y["Title"]);
}
```

or

```
static int CompareDicts(Dictionary<string, string> x, Dictionary<string, string> y) {
  return String.Compare(x["Title"]+"xyz",y["Title"]+"xyz");
}
```

And then to sort

```
list.Sort(CompareDicts);
```

Edit: For a bunch of Sort functions on a List, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx

Comment: handy using delegate :
list.Sort((x,y) =>{ return String.Compare(x["Title"],y["Title"]); });

Answer (score 0):

```
var dicts = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

// populate dictionaries.

var sorted = dicts.OrderBy(x => x.ContainsKey("Title") ? x["Title"] : string.Empty));
```

Comment: For his second modified Title: var sort2 = dicts.OrderBy(x => x.ContainsKey("Title") ? x["Title"] + "xyz" : string.Empty);

Answer (score -2):

LINQ is the solution here.

```
dictionary.OrderBy(o => o.Key)
dictionary.OrderByDescending(o => o.Key)
```

And for the modified version

```
dictionary.OrderBy(o => o.Key + "xyz")
dictionary.OrderByDescending(o => o.Key + "xyz")
```

Comment: This sorts a `Dictionary<>`, not a `List<Dictionary<>>`